# Cannot update a component (``) while rendering a different component (`Router.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Router.Consumer`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

In react application I am trying to render main header and submenu bar directly from App.js. Which is like outside of any Route.

But getting below warning whenever some state update is happening in UserPanel component which is in main header

below is UserPanel component

```js
export default function UserPanel() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.shared.isAuthenticated);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(sharedActions.setIsAuthenticated(authHelper.isAuthenticated()));
    }, []);

    const onLogoutClick = () => {
        authHelper.logout();
        dispatch(sharedActions.setIsAuthenticated(false));
        history.push('/');
    }

    return (
        <div className='user-section'>
            { isAuthenticated &&
                <div >
                    <span className='name-section'>{authHelper.userName()}</span>
                    <span className='logout' onClick={onLogoutClick}> Logout</span>
                </div>}

        </div>
    );
}
```

below is APP component,

```
function App() {
   return (
    <div>
        <div className='top-bar' style={{ backgroundColor: '#002c89' }}>
            <UserPanel></UserPanel>
        </div>

        <Spinner></Spinner>

        <RouteConfig />//Router is inside that component
       
    </div>
 );
 }
 export default App
```

Comment: I believe the warning is in the `history.push('/')`, in which you are redirecting to this route. while the `dispatch()` is being called.

Comment: But even redirection or navigation never happening. How can I fix it ?